# how to import require.cache and require.resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js

- Since i'm using module type in package.json or `import` instead of require.
- how can i import require.cache and require.resolve
- i'm trying to reload a file and update changes made.

```js
// error: require is not defined
delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./index.js`)];
```

- I tried till now

```js
// This runs with no issues but doesn't update the changes.
import { resolve } from 'node:path';
import { createRequire } from 'node:module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
delete require.cache[resolve(`./index.js`)];
```

- without path

```js
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./index.js`)];
```

- But this doen't update the changes made in `index.js`

Expected Result

- If i reload specific file and it should update the changes made to file (`index.js`).

Comment: What kind of behavior you are expecting from the imported module? Because what you need is not possible but I have a workaround based on your requirement.

Comment: i just want to reload file file using command or something without restarting whole app, so if i made changes in `index.js` and if i reload it should update changes made in `index.js`

Comment: I can't count this as an answer, so I am just adding a comment. Maybe it might help you. You can do `new Worker("./module.js").` You can combine it with a file watcher. Then you will be able to spawn new workers whenever your file changes. Hope it helps.

Comment: No this doesn't work in my scenerio.